# web forms and web api integration

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms

Can anyone please provide me your inputs on how to proceed. the below requirement.

I have web application developed in VS professional 2015 and have separate Web API application. So far the existing web application implemented in 3 layered architecture. Now we wanted to implement the new pages using Web API calls without 3 layered architecture.

First of all, I wanted to create a infrastructure/architecture in my web application to call the web API application. So that all the new page requests go through this infrastructure/architecture and call web API.

Please help me with your valuable inputs/suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use angular js or jquery to get data via ajax. Server initial page as static html file.

Answer (score 0):

as we are using `API` there is no need to create a complex infrastructure/architecture unless one is willing to use `ReactJs` or `AngularJs`.
Its even not mandatory for them too but it will let you keep the code clean. you just simply need to call the `API` using JavaScript
For example you've a API controller method and wish to access it.

Simple Method of products

```
#region Get Method
    // GET api/product

    [Queryable]

    [Route("Products")]
    [Route("All")]

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var products = _productServices.GetAllProducts();
            var productEntities = products as List<ProductEntity> ?? products.ToList();
            if (productEntities.Any())
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, productEntities);
            }

            throw new ApiDataException(1000,"No Products Found",HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

just call the respected method from ajax like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var a = "Test";
$.ajax({
    url: "v1/products/product/All",
    type: "GET",
    data: { a : a },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});});
```

Hope This helps